# How to Create Mapped drive with Hidden attribute

Tags: c#

I have created a mapped drive but its shown in explorer. I how can I keep it active but hidden?

Here is my code.

```
//creating map drive 
string pDriveLetter = "z:";
string pDestPath = @"\\192.168.20.35\MyShare
string pUserName = @"192.168.20.35\"+"Administrator";
string pPassword = "Pass@123";

IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class();
network.MapNetworkDrive(pDriveLetter, pDestPath, Type.Missing, pUserName, pPassword);
```

Comment: What / why are you doing this? Seems an iffy solution.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to copy files from the mapped location using windows service. But do not want to show the map drive to the users of the machine. @Tony

Comment: Why does it need to be mapped if you don't want users to see it? Why not just copy using the network address?

Comment: Try using a special user account to run your service. Drive mappings are user-specific.

Comment: can i pass username and password to use network address?

Comment: From a service? Well you could use a special account as suggested by @OndrejTucny but I'd be using UNC paths,as mapped drives is a large tin of worms